# How do I stop my iMessages appearing on my MacBook Air?

Tags: mac, messages, macos, accounts

I updated my MacBook Air to El Capitain (OS X 10.11)
I would rather not have my messages appearing on my Mac when others are using it.
I have tried **System Preferences** but I cannot find the Accounts tab in my settings.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use a different account for other users maybe?

Answer (score 2):

The best practice would be to have other users set up with their own logins on your Mac or to use the Guest account.  They would never see your messages in that case.

But, if you really wish to disable iMessages from appearing on your Mac:

- Go to **Messages**
- Open the **Preferences** Messages > Preferences or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
- Go to the **Accounts** tab
- In the iMessage account uncheck "Enable this account"

[image: Messages Settings]

Answer (score 0):

This is how you really do it ; )  Makes a little more sense.
http://www.imore.com/how-enable-and-disable-notification-banners-mac

System Preferences\Notifications\Messages "Message Alert Style = None"
There is other settings there to make it even more private.

Very Easy!  Enjoy!

Comment: That doesn't prevent users from opening the Messages app and looking at them. Also, welcome to Ask Different.  Cheers!